# JS turn string into variable

Tags: javascript

I have a json feed that returns an array of google map points.  The issue is that it returns everything as a string.   I send icon to a google map script. In the example below you will see SQUARE_PIN.  This is a variable not a string and it adds the quotes around it preventing it from rendering the variable.  Is there a easy way of fixing this.

```
{
    "title":false,
    "lat":"44.7930232",
    "lng":"-89.7031784",
    "icon":{
        "path":"SQUARE_PIN",
        "fillColor":"#FF0000",
        "fillOpacity":1,
        "strokeColor":"",
        "strokeWeight":0,
        "micon":"<\/span>"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is is supposed to be ? Where is the code that generate this ?

Comment: so you want it to be `"path": SQUARE_PIN`?

Comment: is the variable `SQUARE_PIN` in your code, or do you get the content of it from the API?

Comment: `pathValue = obj.icon.path === "SQUARE_PIN" ? SQUARE_PIN : SOMETHING_ELSE;`.

Comment: object / window["your_string_variable"]

Comment: An API can only return a string to you, it can't return "a variable". The issue is not that "quotes prevent it from rendering the variable", the issue is that you're expecting something which isn't possible. You'll need to map the name "SQUARE_PIN" to some value yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose you have your JSON stored in an object called `obj`. Also, let's suppose that the variable you intend to use is inside another object, called `obj2` (could be `window` if the variable is global). In this case you can do this:

```
obj.icon.path = obj2[obj.icon.path];
```

and then use `obj`.